# How to add a custom serializer/format for Java zoneddatetime with fabric8 maven plugin?

Tags: java, java-time, fabric8, zoneddatetime, fabric8-maven-plugin

I am using fabric8 maven plugin to autogenerate Java classes for a CRD from it's yaml file. One of the fields is:

```
updated_time:
  format: date-time
  type: string
```

It's getting converted to a `java.time.zoneddatetime` field:

```
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC", pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
private java.time.ZonedDateTime updated_time;
```

I want to change the pattern above to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` , a timestamp with offset, so it can parse timestamps like  `2023-08-07T06:43:19+00:00`.
How can I achieve this? On java-generator-maven-plugin v6.2.0, open to upgrade.

Comment: A zone is more than just an offset, so you may want to switch to `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: How do I do that? The Java code is autogenerated.

Comment: That's a good question, I have no idea… Hopefully, it is in the docs of fabric8.

Comment: This is not supported at the moment, the field format is hard-coded.
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/a7c630bbd368a976d6b0e72287dcf4f7348c54bd/java-generator/core/src/main/java/io/fabric8/java/generator/nodes/JObject.java#L221

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 6.8.1 of the fabric8 java-generator has been released and includes the relevant fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment in the fabric8 java-generator.
A date-time field should be RFC 3339 according to the [OpenAPI spec](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/).

Would you mind elaborating on the use-case/project that is emitting the incorrect date format?

Anyhow, the viable workaround would be to comment out `format: date-time` in the CRD before the generation, so that you can receive a `String`.

Note on the version:
I do believe that you are using java-generator with version > 6.8 as native support for date-time has only been [recently released](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/releases/tag/v6.8.0).

Comment: The date I mentioned in the question(2023-08-07T06:43:19+00:00) seems to fit the RFC 3339 standard: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/GNUDateAndRFC3339#:~:text=RFC%203339%20is%20an%20RFC,some%20Prometheus%20tools%20use%20it.
The project emitting the date format is in another language and out of my hand. Changing the field type to string is not ideal, as I would like to stick to the original CRD yaml.

Comment: Sadly the proposed date doesn't conform to the specification, it should be something like: `2023-08-07T06:42:19Z` ( [reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) ).

I'm afraid this is a bug in the project producing it ... if it's open-source we can file an issue, if not, please report it somehow.

You can automate the workaround with something like `kustomize`, but I'm not sure how to help any further ...

Comment: I step back :-)
I'm reading again the specification and using the time offset is indeed allowed by the spec.
Let's follow up on this upstream issue: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/5382
We will ship a fix soon, thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks. For now, I'll just comment out the format.

Comment: I provided the relevant fix [here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/5384), feel free to review the changes.